# Azure B2C Graph API - Forcing a user to change passwords on next login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking to use the graph api in order to force a user to reset his/her password on next login.

If I send the user object Id along with **"forceChangePasswordNextLogin": true** I get a successful response. However, the user's account is not actually set to force a password change.

The only way I can get the user prompted to change passwords is if I also send a value for the password along with forceChangePasswordNextLogin. Obviously the problem with this is that an existing user would not know the value of the "current password" and would not be able to change passwords.

Comment: How did you do this? I'm getting "The property 'forceChangePasswordNextLogIn' does not exist on type"

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set the prompt behavior to "true" or add "&prompt=login"?

It could be that after you are setting forceChangePasswordNextLogin, your app is still using the cached token to sign the user in.

When you change the user's password, it kills all existing tokens, which is why you are seeing the change password screen... because it is trying to get the user to sign in again.

If instead, you force the user to sign in again, you will probably get the change password screen as well!

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response - The cached token is an interesting theory but I dont think that is it. If I create a new user with forceChangePasswordNextLogin set to false and before logging in with that user, I update it to true, it will not force me to reset the password upon first login...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your issue is related to that own [Azure AD B2C SignUp-SignIn policy with MFA turned on - Custom Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592570/azure-ad-b2c-signup-signin-policy-with-mfa-turned-on-custom-login-page).

In short it explains that `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` is only compatible with sign-in policies. If you are using a sign-in/sign-up policy, you will have to implement the functionality yourself.