# Not prompting change password on First SignIn

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using `Graph API` to create user and this is how i am creating a user

```
 let payload = {
    "displayName": value.data.displayName,
    "identities": [
      {
        "signInType": "userName",
        "issuer": "{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com",
        "issuerAssignedId": value.data.memberNumber
      },
      {
        "signInType": "emailAddress",
        "issuer": "{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com",
        "issuerAssignedId": value.data.email
      }
    ],
    "passwordProfile": {
      "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
      "password": value.password
    },
    "passwordPolicies": "DisableStrongPassword"
  }
```

When i create user using `"forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true` in `passwordProfile`, i always get an error shown in image below i.e. `password has expired` even on first login.

[image]

Comment: Could be due to forceChangePasswordNextLogin is only compatible with sign-in policies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830917/azure-b2c-graph-api-forcing-a-user-to-change-passwords-on-next-login

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a limitation currently.

You can refer to [a previous similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55758050/ad-b2c-forcechangepasswordnextlogin-for-user-flow-sign-in-v2-doesnt-initiate) to learn about the sign-in policy. The sign-in policy validates a user credential by sending a `grant_type=password` request to the Azure AD B2C directory. If the `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` property is set to `true`, this request returns an "user_password_expired" error. The sign-in policy handles this error by displaying the "Invalid email address/user or password" error.

So as Chris Padgett suggested, you can create a custom attribute (e.g. **ForceResetPasswordNextLogin**), set this to `true` when you create the local account, and then issue this as an application claim from the sign-in policy to your B2C application.

After sign-in, if it is set to `true`, then your B2C application can initiate the password reset policy. After password reset, then your B2C application can set it to `false`.

[Custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview) is also a choice.

Comment: It’s not supported. Our graph api sample point out that the flag must be set to false. Here is a sample with custom policies https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon